# mysql counting without using having

Tags: mysql

So I'm asked to try and convert this statement:

```
    SELECT        C.cid, C.cname
    FROM           Customer C, Buys B
    WHERE        C.cid = B.cid
    GROUP BY  C.cid
    HAVING       count(pid) > 100
```

to the same thing but not use the `HAVING` clause. I've been trying to figure it out for the last hour or so but am unsure on how to do this properly. I've been trying to figure out how to use the `WHERE` clause properly. You can only use the aggregate functions using the `HAVING` clause correct?

This is what the tables look like

```
Product(pid, name, price, mfgr)
Buys(cid, pid)
Customer(cid, cname, age)
```

Comment: Try something on the lines of `select * from (select cid, cname, count(*) as counter from customer c inner join buys b on c.cid=b.cid group by cid, cname) result where counter > 100`

Comment: @zfus thanks for the help. appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply quoting @zfus answer in comment, just so this question appears to have an answer in the list to avoid further traffic.

```
SELECT cid, cname 
FROM (
    SELECT cid, cname, count(*) AS counter 
    FROM customer c 
    INNER JOIN buys b on (c.cid=b.cid) 
    GROUP BY cid, cname
) AS result 
WHERE counter > 100
```

Comment: I was going to post the answer when I was able to get the chance to.